# Changing the amount of bars per page in Sibelius for Composition pieces

Tags: sibelius

How do I format the layout in Sibelius so that there are 4 bars per line on each page? I currently have 7 and it makes the notes too small and squished to read them clearly. How do I make the bars "bigger" so as 4 take up the width of one page? Help!

Answer (score 2):

Click on a barline and press the return key. This will then put this barline at the end of a line. So, if you click on the 4th barline of the first line, and then press return, it will move bar 5 to the next line. Repeat this for all subsequent lines.

Comment: Why do it the hard way yourself, when Sibelius has an option to do it automatically?

Comment: Totally agree @alephzero. The other answer is better and I, for one, upvoted it...

Answer (score 2):

Layout tab -> Breaks -> Auto breaks. It's normally off by default, but you can enable Auto System Breaks, and then choose to specify the number of bars at which to break off the system.